# Classify isolated singular points for $f(z) = \frac{z^3(z^2 -1)(z-2)^2 e^\frac1{z^2}}{\sin^2(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How to solve

> classify all the isolated singular points for
> $$f(z) = \frac{z^3(z^2 -1)(z-2)^2 e^\frac1{z^2}}{\sin^2(z)}$$

I solved the whole number except for zero.
But I don't know how to solve it at zero.
because In other integers, $e^{1/z^{2}}$ was analytic, so there was no problem, but at 0, $e^{1/z^{2}}$ was not analytic, making it difficult to solve.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thank you! I edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

Define
$$ g(z)=\frac{z^2(z^2 -1)(z-2)^2}{\sin^2(z)}, z\neq0, g(0)=-\frac{4}{\pi^2} $$
and hence $g(z)$ is analytic near $z=0$ and $g(0)\neq0$.
Also note
$$ f(z)=\frac{z^3(z^2 -1)(z-2)^2e^{\frac{1}{z^2}}}{\sin^2(z)}=g(z)ze^{\frac{1}{z^2}}=g(z)\bigg(z+\frac1z+\frac1{2!}z^3+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!z^{2n-1}}+\cdots\bigg) $$
which contains infinite many terms of $\frac1{z^{2n-1}}$ and so $z=0$ is an essential singularity point.